# How to skip releasing a build artifact in Azure VSTS CD pipeline if there is no new version of the build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a release definition which delivers a bunch of asp.net core services along with an Angular app.

Most service are not updated very often so the question is how to compare an artifact version with already deployed into an environment and skip if the latest version had been deployed before?

We have multiple environments in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible, at least natively, you can calculate file hashes and dont deploy if they match, another option would be using path triggers to filter when an app is build. for example, your directory structure looks like this:

```
root
|--app1
|--app2
etc
```

you can define path filters in your yaml build like this:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - app1/*
      - sharedlibs/* (if you have them)
```

this way build will only trigger if there are any changes to files in those directories

Comment: Thanks. Builds are handled. Each build artifact has a version. Issue that release always picks up all of the artifacts, even if only one service changed. Wondering if there is a way to know which artifact version is published from the pipeline.

Comment: check release environment variables, it should have a variable for each artifact, but to me it seems you need separate release pipelines for separate applications

Comment: But we have one app (Angular SPA) which calls multiple services (there can be a chain of calls). So if any service code changed we have a service specific build and app release triggered. But the release will be deploying all services because the Angular is "master" release.

I see how to find out artifact version. Is there a way to see what version is currently deployed? I can make a service call to get it's verion but app can be stopped by release so it may not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional release environment to check current artifact version through PowerShell (e.g. Build.SourceVersion, check [variables in release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch#default-variables)), then fail task if there was already successfully released.

For Staging environment, choose After environment option and select previous environment.

On the other hand, since you have mentioned most service are not updated very often, you could use 4c74356b41's suggestion to filter build, to only build and release the changes you want.